# MySQL query for multiple table data

Tags: mysql

I'm searching for a solution to a problem within MySQL which doesn't sound too complicated, I thought.

Basically I want to use two tables.
The first does contain an electronic component list like

```
ID  Description  Value  AdditonalInfo
 1  Resistor     1.0R   R0402
 2  Capacitor    100nF  C0805
 3  Capacitor    10nF   C0603
 ...
```

I want to store information about the sourcing within a second table.

```
ID  Component    Manufacturer Partnumber  Timestamp
 1  2            TDK          XXXYYYZZZ   5
 2  2            Kemet        AAABBBCCC   10
 3  1            Multicomp    111222333   3
 ...
```

As you can see, it should be possible to add more than one manufacturer for each component.

Now, I want to generate a single table (a view) which should contain
all component information AND if present, the latest entry of the manufacturer.

For the given example that would be

```
ID  Description  Value  AdditonalInfo Manufacturer Partnumber
 1  Resistor     1.0R   R0402         Multicomp    111222333
 2  Capacitor    100nF  C0805         Kemet        AAABBBCCC
 3  Capacitor    10nF   C0603         (NULL)
```

Would this be possible within a single query? Or at least with some kind of query which
generates the final table? I could not find out, if the JOIN command would do that.

I would appreciate any help or hints to find a solution for this.
Thanks!

Comment: I can generate this table in one single query, but it might be not so performant. Is that okay? If so, add your DML and DDL queries.

Comment: `OUTER JOIN` plus `GROUP BY` component `HAVING Timestamp = max(Timestamp)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query should give you what you are after.

It takes all the `components`, and then for each component shows the matching entries in the sub-query against the `sourcing` table which groups the components by the latest entry.

The sub-query is joined based on the component and max(timestamp) to another copy of the sourcing table to get the remaining information required.

```
SELECT a.ID, a.Description, a.Value, a.AdditonalInfo, 
         c.Manufacturer, c.Partnumber
FROM componentTable a
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT component, max(timestamp) AS maxTime
            FROM sourcingTable
            GROUP BY component
       ) b
  ON  a.id = b.component
INNER JOIN sourcingTable c
  ON  b.component = c.component
  AND b.maxTime   = c.timestamp
```

You may need additional bracketing around the `LEFT JOIN` and `INNER JOIN` parts, but give this a try first and let me know if it doesn't work

Comment: Yeah, thanks. That seems to be working fine if you replace b.Manufacturer and b.Partnumber with c.* in the second line of your query.

Answer (score 0):

Have your try this:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 on table1.id = table2.id
```

Comment: With LEFT JOIN, it works partially. But I will get multiple rows for a single component, if the component has multiple manufacturer entries. Is that's the case, I just want to get one row per component with the latest manufacturer entry.

Comment: @TimoKlingeberg can you explain what part doesn't work, and what results you are not seeing that you are expecting to see? It will help understand what might be wrong in the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can get data using query with JOIN, if you have index on Component column:

```
SELECT 
* 
FROM components 
  INNER JOIN store USING(id)
```

This query will enough and you don't need store redundant data.